# Rendering JSON response string in Java Controller like a Scala Controller

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

In a Scala controller, I can simply render a response (for dev pursposes) using the magical `"""`:

```
Ok("""{"key":"value"}"""}
```

In a Java controller, this obviously doesn't work. Is there a quick way to render a JSON string as a response? (that is too long to escape manually without hitting my head against a wall)

I don't want to do:

```
ok("{\"key\":\"value\"}");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `"""` it's feature from `Scala` and `Groovy` programming languages. In Java no analogue.
You can try

```
ok("{'key':'value'}");
```

but it does not always work

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see is to write a small shell script or scala script to do the escaping for you and then copy/paste the output of that into your java file.